# How can I tell if an itinerary is genuine?

Tags: air-travel

I need to know urgently please! Attached photo of the itinerary.

[image]

Comment: Did you make the booking yourself? Why do you think it might not be genuine?

Comment: Can you please add information as to how/where you received this, where you booked and why it might not be genuine?

Comment: Are you questioning the price? If it was booked recently (today, yesterday...) for a flight on Thursday, that is the cost, per a Google Flights search.

Comment: My suspicion is that this is a phishing attempt. The thing is, it would be trivial just to call BA (or the credit card supposedly used) to check, and I'm not sure how we as anonymous strangers on the Internet are supposed to provide an authoritative answer.

Comment: My suspicion is that the price is incorrect, rather than phishing. 3,000 USD for a class M ticket? Maybe a tad expensive...

Answer (score 7):

Just go on the [BA Website](https://www.britishairways.com).

-> Then go to "Manage my Booking".

There you have to enter the Booking reference and your last name, which I assume you know. If it lets you manage your booking, the itinerary is genuine.

Comment: I haven't got the booking number as this is not my flight! I wanted to check if it's a genuine document that was sent to me.

Comment: Ps I tried on the BA my booking only without a booking ref I cannot get in.

Comment: I think that without any information, you could try and call British Airways if they are able to confirm that the itinery is genuine. But I'm not sure they are able to disclose that information to you.

Comment: If you are the traveller, the person or company who made the booking for you will have the booking reference number and should give it to you. If they won’t do that, then I’d be suspicious. If you’re not the traveller, then I guess you have no right to the information; if you paid for the ticket on behalf of someone then again I’d expect them to be happy to let you have the booking reference.

Comment: I have a hard time conceiving why a flight itinerary wouldn't be genuine: how might it be possible for a forger to profit from such a creation?

Comment: @David it's a common phishing technique to send fake receipts with spurious "log in to confirm" links.

Comment: The booking reference is the thing you blacked out labeled PNR

Comment: @choster, yes that's true enough, but nothing in the original post or the illustration showed a link or mentioned any encouragement to click. I thought the OP was merely trying to authenticate the information contained.

Answer (score 3):

Since I'm not yet allowed to comment, this is to supplement Daan van Hoek's answer. The concern seems to be whether the "booking reference" is known. The image in the question shows a blacked-out item labeled "PNR". This is the *same thing* as the booking reference. It should be six characters. If OP is the one who blacked it out, then it should be possible to enter it in Manage My Booking.

Comment: True, though note that even if the PNR is real, the itinerary could still be cancelled or changed later. Conceivably, it could even have been purchased with a stolen credit card and will be cancelled once the theft is discovered. Depending on what the OP's reason for asking, confirming that the booking is legitimate now can only provide so much information.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you mean by "genuine".

It's a valid itinerary for this date and price. These flights do exist and you can book this exactly the same way on the BA website.

We can't tell whether the specific booking is valid. That's up to the person who made the booking.

It's certainly not the cheapest way to get from CHS to LHR on Thursday.

Comment: "It's certainly not the cheapest way to get from CHS to LHR on Thursday." Indeed. 3,000 USD in Class M – low fare, 50% Avios awarded, sounds a liiiiitle fishy.

Comment: @dda: it's not fishy, just very short notice and a one way. It's a regular price from the the BA website. you can get down to $1000 but only with multiple stops